# 503 Service unavailable error in Openshift PHP5.3 application

Tags: php, codeigniter, openshift

I am trying to deploy a  codeigniter application on openshift with haproxy scaling enabled. I am using PHP 5.3 catridge. I am getting 503 No server is available to handle this request error. I tried googling a lot but I couldn't get a precise solution for this. Have already tried to restart the application, but of no use.

Comment: Here's an FAQ that is related to your question which has some suggestions:  https://www.openshift.com/faq/why-am-i-getting-503-errors-service-temporarily-unavailable-on-my-application   Can you review it to see if it helps?

Comment: Please post the output of rhc tail <app name> here so that we can see whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having issues I would check out this CodeIgniter OpenShift quickstart here https://github.com/openshift/CodeIgniterQuickStart. If anything you can take a look and see how this quickstart developer went about building it and then apply it to your application.